# Have a function run for a specific amount of time in C

Tags: c, time, raspberry-pi, modbus

I need to be able to run a piece of code for x amount of seconds and then stop. Something like

```
while(timeElapsed < setTime){
     do whatever
}
```

If someone is curious, what is we're trying to do here is having the program poll an indicator via modbus for a certain amount of seconds, set by the user.So I'm having an input field for the user to set the time the polling function should be running in a loop. This will be done on a raspberry pi, by the way.

Comment: I added the [raspberry-pi] and [modbus] tags for you, since those are very relevant to the best way to do this sort of thing.

Comment: What problem do you encounter?

Comment: You should consult the processor to see how to start a timer. When you learned that, start the timer, have your code execute, and then in the timer ISR, have it to jump after your piece of code. You should figure out how to use flags and modularize your code into functions to make this work.

Comment: @Osiris since I'm not a programmer by trade, I don't know where to start, I found a solution in python almost immediately, but time seems a lot more complicated with C.

Comment: That's very likely an XY problem. A **proper** possible solution depends on the system architecture and exact problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to include time.h header and use difftime function. It will be implemented to check if the elaspsed time reaches the set time.

example:

```
#include <time.h>

void func(float delayInSeconds) {
    time_t startTime;
    time_t now;
    float elapsedTime;
    float setTime = delayInSeconds;

    time(&startTime);
    while (elapsedTime < setTime) {
        //do something...

        now = time(NULL);
        elapsedTime = difftime(now, startTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: `elapsedTime` needs to be initialized before being used.

Comment: You could just use `while (difftime(time(NULL), startTime) < setTime)`, no need for the variables, and no worry about forgetting to initialize them.